# RandomAccesFile and UTF8 line

Tags: java, groovy, utf-8, randomaccessfile

I use a `RandomAccessFile` object to read an UTF-8 French file. I use the `readLine` method.

My Groovy code below:

```
while ((line = randomAccess.readLine())) {
    def utfLine = new String(line.getBytes('UTF-8'), 'UTF-8')
    ++count
    long nextRecordPos = randomAccess.getFilePointer()

    compareNextRecords(utfLine, randomAccess)

    randomAccess.seek(nextRecordPos)
}
```

My problem is `utfLine` and `line` are the same: the accented characters stay like Ã© instead of é. No conversion is done.

Comment: Don't use RandomAccessFile to read characters. Use a BufferedReader, constructed from an InputStreamReader specifying the proper encoding, itself constructed from a FileInputStream.

Comment: Can you show how `randomAccess` was constructed?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, but I need to use a random access for my file.

Comment: @Tunaki I create the instance with def randomAccess = new RandomAccessFile(f, 'r')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this line of code does absolutely nothing. The data is the same. Remove it:

```
def utfLine = new String(line.getBytes('UTF-8'), 'UTF-8')
```

According to the Javadoc, [`RandomAccessFile.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine--) is not aware of character encodings. It reads bytes until it encounters "\r" or "\n" or "\r\n". ASCII byte values are put into the returned string in the normal way. But byte values between 128 and 255 are put into the string literally without interpreting it as being in a character encoding (or you could say this is the raw/verbatim encoding).

There is no method or constructor to set the character encoding in a `RandomAccessFile`. But it's still valuable to use `readLine()` because it takes care of parsing for a newline sequence and allocating memory.

The easiest solution in your situation is to manually convert the fake "line" into bytes by reversing what `readLine()` did, then decode the bytes into a real string with awareness of character encoding. I don't know how to write code in Groovy, so I'll give the answer in Java:

```
String fakeLine = randomAccess.readLine();
byte[] bytes = new byte[fakeLine.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < fakeLine.length(); i++)
    bytes[i] = (byte)fakeLine.charAt(i);
String realLine = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I've tried with: def utfLine = new String(line.getBytes(), 'UTF-8') but the result has been the same.

Comment: Your solution works :) But, why does it work and not the call of line.getBytes() ?

Comment: Because `getBytes()` will escape the values in the 128-255 range into a different sequence of bytes

Comment: It's crazy and not intuitive. Thanks four your help.